# Store syskey key file on a USB

Tags: windows, security

I was toying with syskey today and noticed you could store the key file on a floppy. Obviously floppies and their drives are hard to come by so I wondered if I could store the key file on a USB drive.

I plugged in my USB drive and tried to "save to floppy A:" - it failed unsurprisingly

I went to Disk Management and change the drive letter to 'A:' for the USB drive. Syskey now recognised the drive letter and promptly saved the key file to the pen.

Now I restarted the PC to test if it'd work - it didn't

It asked me to insert drive A:, which was inserted by the way but just couldn't recognise it. It didn't matter whether I restarted with USB already plugged in, with the USB not plugged in, different USB ports.. etc...

I eventually just restored the security files from the regbackup folder to boot back into Windows.

My question is, why didn't it work? is it a limitation of USB themselves? the USB partition style? syskey?

and most importantly is there a way to store these key files on a USB ?

Comment: Wanna use 12 year old software (ie: syskey from XP)? You may need 12 year old hardware...  Simple as that....  ;)

Comment: no, its not as simple as that. syskey is still being used in the current windows OS's ?

Comment: Syskey is different on newer Windows versions, and it certainly doesn't depend on floppies any more. :)  Which version of Windows _are_ you using?

Comment: Does your BIOS support emulating USB keys as a floppy drive?